# Model comparing with statistical test

Tags: t-test, model-comparison, method-comparison

I am comparing few classification models (performance in AUC of ROC curves). I uses  10 times repeated 5 fold cross-validation so I have 50 values of AUC for each model. The key information is, that every 50 resamples are same for each models. So I have same combinations of training set/test for each models.

May I use paired t-test or one sample t-test of AUC differences to test if model performances are different?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a paired t-test, the assumptions should be met. One of them is that your values should come from a normal distribution. The AUC, however, is a [Wilcoxon statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) (see quote below) and therefore violates this assumption.

Now, it just so happens that the Wilcoxon Signed Rank Sum Test tests the same hypothesis as the t-test, but doesn't require normality of the data. I would recommend using that test.

---

Since I started researching a bit on this, I decided I might as well share it here, as it seems relevant for future visitors: In [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7063747) by Hanley and McNeil from 1982 the distributional characteristics of the AUC are explained:

> "It is shown that in such a setting the area represents the probability that a randomly chosen diseased subject is (correctly) rated or ranked with greater suspicion than a randomly chosen non-diseased subject. Moreover, this probability of a correct ranking is the same quantity that is estimated by the already well-studied nonparametric Wilcoxon statistic. "

1. Calculate the standard errors of AUC scores: $
   () = \sqrt{\frac{(1 − ) + (1 − 1)(1 − 2) + (2 − 1)(2 − ^2)}{_1_2}}$, 
   where $Q1 = \frac{}{2 − }$ and $Q2= \frac{2AUC^2}{1+AUC}$
2. Calculate the correlation coefficient $r$ between the two areas. This is probably not zero, because the AUCs *"will tend to fluctuate in tandem when derived from a single sample"*. How to calculate $r$ is outlined in [their 1983 paper](http://pubs.rsna.org/doi/pdf/10.1148/radiology.148.3.6878708) on page 840.
3. Calculate the standard error of the difference in AUCs between two models: \begin{equation*}
   SE\left(AUC_{1}- AUC_{2}\right) = \sqrt{SE^2(AUC_{1}) + SE^2(AUC_{2})-2r\cdot SE(AUC_{1}) SE(AUC_{2})}
   \end{equation*}.
4. Calculate $Z$, which is supposed to be a standard normally distributed random variable, so you can just compare it to the good old critical values 1.96: \begin{equation}
   z = \frac{AUC_1 - AUC_2}{SE(AUC_1 - AUC_2)}
   \end{equation}

Once you have steps 1 and 2 down, the rest is simple enough.