# AUROC and cross validation for binary classification

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, auc

I am trying to compare the AUC of multiple binary classifiers to see whether one is significantly better than the other. For each classifier I perform 5-fold cross validation.
What I came up with so far is using a Wilcoxon Signed Rank Sum test, as described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/323817/142615). I am wondering if this is the best approach, as I also have the ROC curves and I know that DeLong's test can be used to compare these. My concern is that I only have 5 "samples" from the cross validation, leading to a low statistical power.

Wouldn't it be better to compare the mean ROC curve for each classifier using DeLong's test? If there is a reason why it is not recommended to compare mean ROC curves, what is it?